# Prove $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification, nilpotence

Let $A$ be an $n$ x $n$ real matrix. Prove $0$ is
eigen value of $A$.

PROOF:

Let $m∈ℤ^{+}$

so $A^{m}$**x**$=λ^{m}$**x**

there exists$m≥1$ s.t $A^{m}=0$.

$0=λ^{m}$**x**, but $x≠0$, so $λ^{m}=0$

$m>0$ , so $λ^{m}=0$ IFF so $λ=0$.

so all $λ=0$

Comment: Quick tip for formatting: try to get the entirety of a mathematical expression between `$...$` whenever possible. So for example, instead of `$A$**x**$=λ$**x**`, try `$A \mathbf{x} = \lambda \mathbf{x}$`.

Comment: The proof is completely correct and understandable

Comment: Actually, there is an issue with your proof: for an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with real entries, it is not necessarily true that there is a non-zero $\mathbf x \in \Bbb R^n$ and scalar $\lambda$ such that $A \mathbf x = \lambda \mathbf x$

Comment: Your proof looks pretty good. The phrasing/structure can be tightened in some places, but the method is for the most part sound sound. Some constructive criticism: I'd start by saying, "given an arbitrary eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, we proceed to show that it must be zero. The definition of an eigenvalue gives us that there is a vector $v$ such that $Av=\lambda v$..." You don't want to start by saying there must be an eigenvector, because that's not true.

Comment: @BenGrossmann if i change the proof to say that there is a non-zero $x∈C^{n}$ and scalar $λ$ such that  $Ax=λx$ then there would no longer be that error?

Comment: @not_tiger A *complex* scalar $\lambda$. Yes, that works

Comment: Why has the question disappeared ?

Comment: sorry, trying to change it around to resmemble the one below and got confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rewrite of your proof that I think is an improvement.

---

**Proof:** We are given that $A$ is $n \times n$, and that $A$ is nilpotent. Let $m$ denote the smallest positive integer for which $A^m = 0$.

First, we show that $A$ must have $0$ as an eigenvalue. Let $\mathbf x \in \Bbb R^n$ be any non-zero vector. Let $j_0$ denote the smallest positive integer $j$ for which $A^j\mathbf x = 0$; we note that such an integer exists because taking $j = m$ yields $A^j\mathbf x = 0 \mathbf x = 0$.  We can see that $A(A^{j_0 - 1} \mathbf x) = 0 \cdot \mathbf x$, and $A^{j_0 - 1} \mathbf x \neq \mathbf 0$. So, $A^{j_0 - 1}\mathbf x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $\lambda = 0$.

Now, suppose that $\lambda$ is an eigenvector of $A$. Let $\mathbf x \in \Bbb R^n$ be an associated eigenvector so that $\mathbf x \neq \mathbf 0$ and $A \mathbf x  = \lambda \mathbf x$.

**Claim:** $A^k \mathbf x = \lambda^k \mathbf x$.

**Proof of claim:** We proceed by induction

*Base case:* $A^1 \mathbf x= \lambda^1 \mathbf x$.

*Inductive step:* If $A^n \mathbf x = \lambda^n \mathbf x$, then
$$
A^{n+1} \mathbf x = A (A^n \mathbf x) = A \lambda^n \mathbf x = 
\lambda^n A \mathbf x = \lambda^n \cdot \lambda \mathbf x = \lambda^{n+1} \mathbf x. \quad \square
$$

We know that $A^m = 0$. By the claim, it follows that
$$
\mathbf 0 = 0 \cdot \mathbf x = A^m \mathbf x = \lambda^m \mathbf x.
$$
If $\lambda^m \mathbf x = 0$, then we must have $\lambda^m = 0$. However, $m$ is a positive integer, so $\lambda^m = 0$ implies that $\lambda = 0$.

That is, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda = 0$. So, $\lambda = 0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$.